# Implement tail with awk

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, awk, tail

I am struggling with this awk code which should emulate the tail command

```
num=$1;
{
    vect[NR]=$0;
    
}
END{
    for(i=NR-num;i<=NR;i++)
            print vect[$i]
}
```

So what I'm trying to achieve here is an tail command emulated by awk/
For example consider `cat somefile | awk -f tail.awk 10`
should print the last 10 lines of a text file, any suggestions?

Comment: `awk -f tail.awk num=10`, 10 by itself will be interpreted as a filename. Good luck.

Comment: Do you really need to store the whole file?

Comment: @Johnsyweb well no, but that's the approach i've thought to use, got some other ideas ? fell free to post them :)

Comment: Since you're clearly doing this as an exercise, any code I post wouldn't help you.

Comment: It wasn't an question I've got today in the operating systems exam, I was just being curious if there are some other viable alternatives

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
for(i=NR-num;i<=NR;i++)
    print vect[$i]
```

`$` indicates a positional parameter. Use just plain `i`:

```
for(i=NR-num;i<=NR;i++)
    print vect[i]
```

The full code that worked for me is:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN{
        num=ARGV[1];
        # Make that arg empty so awk doesn't interpret it as a file name.
        ARGV[1] = "";
}
{
        vect[NR]=$0;
}
END{
        for(i=NR-num;i<=NR;i++)
                print vect[i]
}
```

You should probably add some code to the `END` to handle the case when `NR` < `num`.

Comment: when i try to cat the text file into awk i still get an error on ARGV[1]
-----------------------------------------------------------
cat test1.txt | awk -f tailawk 10

Comment: consider that i've added a BEGIN{num=ARGV[1]}

Answer (score 9):

All of these answers store the *entire* source file.  That's a horrible idea and will break on larger files.

Here's a quick way to store only the number of lines to be outputted (note that the more efficient `tail` will always be faster because it doesn't read the entire source file!):

```
awk -vt=10 '{o[NR%t]=$0}END{i=(NR<t?0:NR);do print o[++i%t];while(i%t!=NR%t)}'
```

more legibly (and with less [code golf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_golf)):

```
awk -v tail=10 '
  {
    output[NR % tail] = $0
  }
  END {
    if(NR < tail) {
      i = 0
    } else {
      i = NR
    }
    do {
      i = (i + 1) % tail;
      print output[i]
    } while (i != NR % tail)
  }'
```

Explanation of legible code:

This uses the [modulo operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) to store only the desired number of items (the `tail` variable).  As each line is parsed, it is stored on top of older array values (so line 11 gets stored in `output[1]`).

The `END` stanza sets an increment variable `i` to either zero (if we've got fewer than the desired number of lines) or else the number of lines, which tells us where to start recalling the saved lines.  Then we print the saved lines in order.  The loop ends when we've returned to that first value (after we've printed it).

You can replace the `if`/`else` stanza (or the [ternary clause](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operator) in my golfed example) with just `i = NR` if you don't care about getting blank lines to fill the requested number (`echo "foo" |awk -vt=10 …` would have nine blank lines before the line with "foo").

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `-v num=10` to the awk commandline to set the value of `num`. And start at `NR-num+1` in your final loop, otherwise you'll end up with `num+1` lines of output.

Comment: Yes thx I've forgot to increment nr-num as i've tried a backward read from nr to nr-num and swapped indexes and forgot to increment, thx anyway

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you:

```
awk '{a=a b $0;b=RS;if(NR<=v)next;a=substr(a,index(a,RS)+1)}END{print a}' v=10
```

Comment: I'd upvote this if it were explained. I can understand it, but it needs explanation for everyone.

Answer (score 0):

`tail` really depends on 2 totally different scenarios :

1. Coming in from the pipe, yes follow the standard `arr[ NR % tail_n ]` approach others have mentioned.
2. Being a fixed file though, (or whatever virtual device that's "seekable"), especially if the file is huge and what the # rows you're looking for is substantial, it pays to do a quick `wc -l` up front and skip all the temp array storage :

---

```
( time ( mawk2 -v ___='3.14159 %' 'BEGIN { 

    index(__ = ARGV[ARGC-!_],_ = "\47") && 
     gsub(_,(_ "\\" _)_, __)

     (_ = "LC_ALL=C gwc -l "(_ __)_) | getline
     close(_)

     printf("\f\f\t %d...\f\f\n",
           ___ = int(((_ = 100) - ___) * $1 /_)) >>("/dev/stderr")

     FS = RS } ___ < NR' "$f" ) | pv ) | xxh128sum | gcat -b ;

  sleep 4;

 ( time ( LC_ALL=C  gtail -n 4654474 "$f" ) | pv ) | xxh128sum | gcat -b
 out9: 1.39GiB 0:00:07 [ 193MiB/s] [ 193MiB/s] [ <=> ]
```

---

```
 ( mawk2 -v ___='3.14159 %' "$f" )  

 5.49s user 1.86s system 99% cpu 7.370 total

 1  607efeee007a7e50cc06ce287a82e78f  stdin
```

---

```
 ( LC_ALL=C  gtail -n 4654474 "$f" ; )  

 3.71s user 6.12s system 123% cpu 7.950 total

 1  607efeee007a7e50cc06ce287a82e78f  stdin
```

Depending on the file's total size to row count ratio, `tail`'s speed is anywhere from 1.0x-2.5x of `awk-tail`, specifically for fixed files not the pipe.