# using awk script to print last n rows of a text file

Tags: awk

I need a script to print last n rows of a text file. the text file names and number of rows can be varied and I want to call only script to print last n rows of any text files. I know for first n row I can use NR < n; print but how can I do it for last n row as number of rows can be varied.- thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Implement tail with awk](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9101296/implement-tail-with-awk)

Answer (score 2):

There is a unix tool for exactly that purpose, called `tail`. To get the last 100 rows of file, you would use `tail -n 100 file`, then use the output directly or pipe it to other programs like awk.

Comment: Yes, I know about tail but I do not know how to write in in a script! Sorry I am so new in awk!

Comment: @Sajjad If you really need tails functionality inside awk, see for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9101296/implement-tail-with-awk

Answer (score 2):

To do this natively in awk, you have to remember the lines as you see them:

```
awk -v n=10 '
    {line[NR]=$0}
    END {for (i=NR-(n-1); i<=NR; i++) print line[i]}
' file
```

To save memory, we don't need to remember the whole file; use

```
    {line[NR]=$0; if (NR>n) delete line[NR-n]}
```

However it is simpler to reverse the file, print the *first* n lines, and re-reverse the output

```
tac file | awk -v n=10 'NR <= n' | tac
```

But using `tail` is much simpler that all that

Answer (score 1):

as an exercise, there is another version trading space vs time to achieve the same

```
$ awk -v n=10 'NR==FNR{a=NR;next} FNR>(a-n)' file{,}
```

scan the files first to get the number of lines and use to filter last n rows second time.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat file
1
2
3
4

$ cat tst.awk
{ rec[NR % n] = $0 }
END {
    for (i=NR+1+(n<NR?0:n-NR); i<=(NR+n); i++) {
        print rec[i % n]
    }
}

$ awk -v n=2 -f tst.awk file
3
4
```

The complexity when setting the starting value of `i` is to accommodate cases where you ask to print more records than exist in the file, e.g.:

```
$ awk -v n=6 -f tst.awk file
1
2
3
4
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this script a try:

```
{
  lines[(i=(++i%n))]=$0;
}
END {
  if (NR>=n) {
    linessize=n;
  } else {
    linessize=NR;
    i=0;
  }
  for(j=1;j<=linessize;j++) {
    print lines[(i+j)%n];
  }
}
```

File is parsed only once.

An array with **n** elements  **only** is used to buffer the lines read.

The tests:

```
$ printf "one line\n2nd line\n" | ./tail-awk.awk -f script.awk -v n=10
one line
2nd line
$ ./tail-awk.awk  -f script.awk -v n=10 <(man bash)
       attempted.  When a process is stopped, the shell immediately executes the next command in the sequence.  It  suffices  to
       place the sequence of commands between parentheses to force it into a subshell, which may be stopped as a unit.

       Array variables may not (yet) be exported.

       There may be only one active coprocess at a time.



GNU Bash-4.1                                            2009 December 29                                                 BASH(1)
$ ./tail-awk.awk -f script.awk -v n=5 /etc/apt/sources.list

deb http://archive.debian.org/debian-archive hamm main

deb ftp://ftp.debian.org/debian squeeze contrib

$
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked. How can I edited to call it as a script by using this 'awk -f script.awk file.txt'