# Using awk to print last N rows of file filtered by line

Tags: linux, awk

I've been using

```
awk '/KEYWORD/{print $0}' FILENAME
```

to filter a file, how do I modify the command so as to print the last n lines only?

Comment: Use `tail` on the output

Comment: `awk '/KEYWORD/{print $0}' FILENAME | tail -n n` where `-n` is the option for number of ending rows to output and `n` is you `n` number.

Comment: `awk '/KEYWORD/ { print $0 }'` does the same thing as `grep`, so `grep KEYWORD | tail -n $n` would be enough

Comment: This can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36390128/using-awk-script-to-print-last-n-rows-of-a-text-file

Comment: @Carlos : depends on how big the post-filter size is. If it's `< 1 GB` or so, just use 1 `awk` to filter and pipe to 1 more `awk`, this time set `RS = "^$"; FS = "\n"`, jump to the `END { }` section, figure out which field is the N-th last one (keeping in mind that `NF` is 1 more than # of `\n`). If that field (row)'s contents never existed b4, then simply `substr()` from there till the end. Otherwise, I'd prefix that field w/ a custom sep of whacko byte combos, eg `"\371\17\301"`. use `sub()` to clean off everything to left of it, inc the sep, then print the rest. Default to `tail` or array.

Answer (score 0):

To do this in `awk` only, without additional filtering through `tail` or whatever, we can build an N element FIFO buffer into which we put all the  matches. Then we just dump the relevant content from the buffer when done.

```
BEGIN { N = 10; i = 0 }

/keyword/ { fifo[i] = $0; i = (i + 1) % N }

END { for (x = -N; x < 0; x++)
      { j = (i + x + N) % N
        if (fifo[j])
           print fifo[j] } }
```