# Print first few and last few lines of file through a pipe with "..." in the middle

Tags: bash, shell, tail

## Problem Description

This is my file

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

I would like to send the cat output of this file through a pipe and receive this

```
% cat file | some_command
1
2
...
9
10
```

---

## Attempted solutions

Here are some solutions I've tried, with their output

```
% cat temp | (head -n2 && echo '...' && tail -n2)
1
2
...
```

```
% cat temp | tee >(head -n3) >(tail -n3) >/dev/null
1
2
3
8
9
10
# I don't know how to get the ...
```

```
% cat temp | sed -e 1b -e '$!d'
1
10

% cat temp | awk 'NR==1;END{print}'
1
10
# Can only get 2 lines
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An awk:

```
awk -v head=2 -v tail=2 'FNR==NR && FNR<=head
FNR==NR && cnt++==head {print "..."}
NR>FNR && FNR>(cnt-tail)' file file
```

Or if a single pass is important (and memory allows), you can use `perl`:

```
perl -0777 -lanE 'BEGIN{$head=2; $tail=2;}
END{say join("\n", @F[0..$head-1],("..."),@F[-$tail..-1]);}' file
```

Or, an awk that is one pass:

```
awk -v head=2 -v tail=2 'FNR<=head
{lines[FNR]=$0}
END{
    print "..."
    for (i=FNR-tail+1; i<=FNR; i++) print lines[i]
}' file
```

Or, nothing wrong with being a caveman direct like:

```
head -2 file; echo "..."; tail -2 file
```

Any of these prints:

```
1
2
...
9
10
```

---

It terms of *efficiency*, here are some stats.

For small files (ie, less than 10 MB or so) all these are less than 1 second and the 'caveman' approach is *2 ms*.

I then created a 1.1 GB file with `seq 99999999 >file`

- The two pass awk: 50 secs
- One pass perl:    10 seconds
- One pass awk:     29 seconds
- **'Caveman':        2 MS**

Comment: Now handle cases where lines count is less than head and tail, and case when head and tail lines intersects ^^

Comment: They all handle overlapping head and tail.

Comment: Especially with large files, the "caveman" approach is the best, because it's the only one that won't read the whole file (`head` stops after a few lines, and `tail` seeks to the end and works its way back). Try the `perl` version with a file that's larger than your available RAM and you're in for a surprise.

Comment: @dawg, I think that by overlapping head and tail, they mean e.g. a case where the file has only three lines.  Given three lines `1`, `2`, and `3`, that last `head`+`tail` solution would print `1`, `2`, `...`, `2`, `3`, which is probably technically correct at least for some phrasings of the problem, but it might also be considered misleading. Looks like the others print the same.

Comment: @ilkkachu: think the case of three line file is at best ambiguous what the 'correct result' is. I think `1\n2\n...\n2\n3` is most correct in my view. What do you think is a better result for that?

Comment: @GuntramBlohm: Agreed and I added a note to that effect. The two pass awk is reasonable as well in that situation.

Comment: @dawg, in this narrow context of this Q, we don't know, since the post doesn't say. But more generally, `1\n2\n...\n2\n3` implies that there's something removed in the part where it says `...`, and that's not true in the case of a three or four-line file. It would make more sense to me to print a three line file just as-is, without the ellipsis. _In general_. Of course we don't know what they're doing in this particular case, if there's a use-case that requires/expects all four lines and the `...`, and where the doubled `2` line makes sense, then that needs to be done.

Answer (score 1):

You may consider this awk solution:

```sh
awk -v top=2 -v bot=2 'FNR == NR {++n; next} FNR <= top || FNR > n-top; FNR == top+1 {print "..."}' file{,}

1
2
...
9
10
```

Answer (score 1):

Two single pass `sed` solutions:

```
sed '1,2b
     3c\
...
     N
     $!D'
```

and

```
sed '1,2b
     3c\
...
     $!{h;d;}
     H;g'
```

Comment: How does this work?  It would be more helpful for future readers with related problems (like a count other than 2) if you commented the code and said what you're doing with the  pattern / hold space.

Answer (score 0):

Assumptions:

- as OP has stated, a solution must be able to work with a stream from a pipe
- the total number of lines coming from the stream is unknown
- if the total number of lines is less than the sum of the `head/tail` offsets then we'll print duplicate lines (we can add more logic if OP updates the question with more details on how to address this situation)

A single-pass `awk` solution that [implements a queue in awk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33110779) to keep track of the most recent N lines; the queue allows us to limit `awk's` memory usage to just N lines (as opposed to loading the entire input stream into memory, which could be problematic when processing a large volume of lines/data on a machine with limited available memory):

```
h=2 t=3

cat temp | awk -v head=${h} -v tail=${t} '
    { if (NR <= head) print $0
      lines[NR % tail] = $0
    }

END { print "..."

      if (NR < tail) i=0
      else           i=NR

      do { i=(i+1)%tail
           print lines[i]
         } while (i != (NR % tail) )
    }'
```

This generates:

```
1
2
...
8
9
10
```

---

Demonstrating the overlap issue:

```
$ cat temp4
1
2
3
4
```

With `h=3;t=3` the proposed `awk` code generates:

```
$ cat temp4 | awk -v head=${h} -v tail=${t} '...'
1
2
3
...
2
3
4
```

Whether or not this is the 'correct' output will depend on OP's requirements.